# conda sklearn error when importing sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda, conda

I am using conda with python3.6 on ubuntu 18, and trying to install sklearn version 0.2 using

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

I am getting in the process some weird massages such as this one

> SafetyError: The package for scikit-learn located at
>   /home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.2-py36hd81dba3_0 appears
>   to be corrupted. The path
>   'lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/weight_vector.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so' has an incorrect size.   reported size: 66016 bytes   actual size:
>   48608 bytes

then I get "done" massage and approval and when I try to import sklearn I get this error:

> ImportError: Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While
>   importing we detected an older version of numpy

What am I missing here? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading numpy?

Comment: @yatu i reinstalled numpy and updated the entire env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a seperate python environment for your project with this command:

```
conda create -n yourenvname python=3.6 scikit-learn
```

This should have scikit included.

Afterwards enable your environment:

```
conda activate yourenvname
```

For more information regarding conda environments [link to documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

---

Besides you could try `conda uninstall scikit-learn` and afterwards install again

Comment: the reinstall did not work, and the idea is to add scikit learn to an existing env, ideas?

Comment: Ok, did you try to export your environment `conda env export > environment.yml` and create it again from scratch with another name? [Documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-the-environment-file)